# How to provide a single function to get data of any derived object through base class pointer?

Tags: c++

i have code like below.
Base is the base class and D1, D2, D3 are derived classes.
D1, D2 and D3 class objects can hold int, float and double values respectively.
I have a vector of base class pointers. Each one of them can point to any of the derived class objects.
Through Base class pointer i should be able to get the data present in any of the derived class.

```
enum Type
{
   INT,
   FLOAT,
   DOUBLE
};
struct Data
{
   Type type;
   union
   {
       int iVal;
       float fVal;
       double dVal;
   };
};
class Base
{
public:
   virtual Data getData() = 0;
};
class D1: public Base
{
   int i;
public:
   virtual Data getData()
   {
       Data data;
       data.type = INT;
       data.iVal = i;
       return data;
   }
};

class D2: public Base
{
     float f;
public:
    virtual Data getData()
    {
       Data data;
       data.type = FLOAT;
       data.fVal = f;
       return data;
    }
};

class D3: public Base
{
     double d;
public:
    virtual Data getData()
    {
       Data data;
       data.type = DOUBLE;
       data.dVal = d;
       return data;
    }
};
```

getData() returns Data object.

Using the type in Data object, i need to extract corresponding value in union.

I am unable to avoid type checking even though i am using virtual function mechanism.

Is there any better way to return data through single interface function ?

**EDIT**: In my project scenario, at runtime it can generate few D1 objects, few D2 objects and so on. I need to pass all these objects to some other module.
So i used `vector<Base *>` to pass on all the objects to the next module.
Is there any better way to pass on all the objects ?

**EDIT**: Any Non-Boost solution exists ?

Comment: why are you not able to avoid the type checking? everything returns a `Data` so what is the need for type checking?

Comment: @Naveen: I need to check type present in Data struct. For ex: if type is INT, i will go and access data.iVal.

Comment: oh ok..I thought you meant you need to check derived class types.

Comment: I updated question, pls check

Comment: @bjskishore123: it depends on what you need to do with the objects in this other module. For example, if you only want to print the data you can easily avoid type checks. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @FireAphis: I just need to read data and create other structures and pass on the data. For reading data, i need to know which type it is.

Comment: @bjskishore123: And what do you do with the data after you read it? I ask this because I'm looking for a generic pattern in your solution. If there is one, most likely type checks could be avoided.

Comment: A non-boost solution would be to reimplement the corresponding boost library :)

Comment: @FireAphis: I need to convert from one structure to another structure. Converting data from one phase to other phase. Like that there are 3 phases in our project. From D1 data, i will form another structure. As the order also important, i need to put all types of objects in a single vector and process one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general I'd prefer to avoid such design at all. But if you absolutely have to make it this way, the easiest and fastest method, imho, is to use [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/any.html).

Update: As it was, absolutely correctly, noted [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/variant.html) may be even more convenient and efficient here, since the used types are known (thanks for the remarks).

Comment: +1: boost::any/boost::variant is the best solution to this problem.

Comment: `boost::variant` seems better in this case since all types are known in advance. Recall that `boost::any` uses the heap and RAII.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to do something similar to the [VARIANT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221627.aspx) struct. Can you explain a bit more about why you are attempting this design?

Answer (score 0):

This might be put a bit hard but: object orientation and polymorphism is about letting objects do something, it is not about querying data from objects.
If this is about printing,sending,storing,... data, you could derive from data and let the derived data objects do the printing,sending,storing,..., but in this case, you don't need the data classes: the owning classes can do this too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing one vector of variant objects, what about passing three vectors, each with just one type in it?

Comment: As the order of objects also important, i need to put all types of objects in a single vector and process one by one. For ex: if i have 3 objects in that vector, i will create 3 corresponding objects which can be used in next phase of the module.